# PowerShell script to tick proxy settings : "Use automatic configuration script" AND "Automatically detect settings"

Tags: powershell, proxy

I want to create a Powershell script to automatically tick the proxy settings "Automatically detect settings" and "Use automatic configuration script" as :
[Proxy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoSBe.png)

So I found some tips, I am able to tick "Use automatic configuration script" with my proxy address with :

```
set-itemproperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name AutoConfigURL -value 'proxy address'
```

And I am able to tick "Automatically detect settings" with

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections'
$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings
$data[8] = 9
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $data
```

But If I try **both** like to put the two codes on the same script it doesn't work and only "Use automatic configuration script" is ticked.

I also saw that I can use the value **0d** from : [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.scripting.vbscript/EGdKXiEcwG4).

But when I tried that the output is *"Error: Input string was not in a correct format."*

Do you have any Idea on how I can do this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Try `[byte[]]$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings` and `Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $data -PropertyType Binary`

Comment: So i tried your lines putting **0d** as value for $data[8]
But I still get the same error : Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
Any other Ideas ? thanks

Comment: Then how do you set the value of byte[8] exactly? I think the error you show refers to that part. Use `$data[8] = 0x0d` or `$data[8] = 13`

Comment: Hi Theo, Thanks for that it worked for me with `$data[8] = 0x0d`

Answer (score 2):

```
[byte[]]$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings
```

change to

```
[byte[]]$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key).DefaultConnectionSettings
```

Overall, this is wonderful, great job Theo, thank you for sharing.

Todd